# Are there a way to know how much of the EEPROM memmory that is used?

Tags: movesense

I have looked trough the "logbook" and "datalogger" APIs and there are no way of telling that the data logger is almost full. I found the API call with the following path "/Mem/Logbook/IsFull". If I have understood it correct this will notify me when log is full and the datalogger has stopped logging.

So my question is: Are there a way to know how much of the memmory is currently in use so that I do a cleanup old data (need to do some calculations on them before they are deleted) before the EEPROM is full and the Datalogger stops recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data memory of Logbook/DataLogger is conceptually a ring buffer. That's why */Mem/DataLogger/IsFull* always returns *false* on Movesense sensor (Suunto uses the same API in its watches where the situation is different). Therefore the sensor never stops recording, it just replaces oldest data with new.

Here are a couple of strategies that you could use:

**Plan A:**

1. Create a new log (POST /Mem/Logbook/Entries => returns the logId for it)
2. Start Logging (PUT /Mem/DataLogger/State: LOGGING)
3. Every once in a while create a new log (POST /Mem/Logbook/Entries). Note: This can be done while logging is ongoing!
4. When you want to know what is the status of the log, read /Mem/Logbook/Entries. When the oldest entry has completely been overwritten, it disappears from the list. Note: The GET /Entries is a heavy operation so you may not want to do it when the logger is running!

**Plan B**

Every now and then start a new log and process the previous one. That way the log never overwrites something you have not processed.

**Plan C**

(Note: This is low level and may break with some future Movesense sensor release)

GET the first 256 bytes of EEPROM chip #0 using the */Component/EEPROM* API. This area contains a number of ExtflashChunkStorage::StorageHeader structs (see: *ExtflashChunkStorage.h*), rest is filled with 0xFF. The last StorageHeader before 0xFF is the current one. With that StorageHeader one can see where the ring buffer starts (*firstChunk*) and where next data is written (*cursor*). The difference of the two is the used memory. (Note: Since it is a ring buffer the difference can be negative. In that case add the "Size of Logbook area - 256" to it)

*Full disclosure: I work for Movesense team*