# Using Datalogger- and EepromService together

Tags: movesense

I am trying to store some data on the device that I do not want to be overwritten by when the datalogger is full. And have run into some minor issues. I was looking for the "eeprom_logbook_app" but could not find it in firmware version 1.6.2 of the device-lib.

I have defined how much space I want for my persistent data and in App.cpp I have used the LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA(offset, size) macro.

where I have used the size of what I want to store as the offset and set the size to be

> (2097152 + 1048576) - (size of data I want to store)

as this was what was returned when I asked the sensor for the eeprom size. (The eeprom is devided between 2 ICs one with 1MB capasity and one with 2MB capacity?)

Then I remembered that there was some talk about ExtflashChunkStorage::StorageHeader being stored as the first 256 bytes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186876/7884072) answer.

So my question is where the data will be offset from and what is the max size I can set as size so that I can subtract the correct amount to fit my data? I presume I at least need to take another 256 bytes off from the size to get my correct storage size.

Comment: I think I have figured this one out and will greate an answer when I have tested. As I have understood now the StorageHeader should bbe automatically placed in the beginning of the datalogger/logbook section of the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment I got this working the only thing you need to do is using the LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA(offset, size) function. 
let's say you want to set aside 256 bits for your own config you could then do this:

```
#define RESERVED_CONFIG 256
#define TOTAL_MEMMORY_SIZE (2097152 + 1048576)

static const uint32_t offset = RESERVED_CONFIG;
static const uint32_t size = TOTAL_MEMMORY_SIZE -offset;
LOGBOK_MEMORY_AREA(offset, size);
```

This will set aside 256 bytes on the start of the EEPROM memory and offset the logbook to accommodate this. As a result, the logbook header will also be moved to the start of the logbook's memory area.